# if data attribute equal and div got class

Tags: jquery

I would like to add a class on a submit button if two conditions are true in a form.

I have an input field with `data-start` attribute and a div with a class in my page. The attribute `data-start` is dynamic and depends on the choice of the user. That's why I would like to know if this data is equal to 0 (others values are possible).

```
<input type='hidden' data-start='0'>

if ($('input').data('start') === 0 && $('div').hasClass('frm_imc')) {
    console.log('ok');
    $('button[type="submit"]').addClass('frm_end');
}
```

This code don't work. Can I have some help please ?

Comment: Did you try ($('input').data('start') == '0' ?

Comment: Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve Remember also that `.data()` getter returns string type in this case, so `"0"` versus `0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return value of the `$()` jQuery function is a jQuery result set (similar to an array of matched elements). So there is no way for that result set object to equal a number primitive value like `0`.

Instead, change your selector to match only when the data attribute is 0, and then check the length is non-zero:

```
if ($('input[data-start=0]').length > 0 && $('div.frm_imc').length > 0) {
    console.log('ok');
    $('button[type="submit"]').addClass('frm_end');
}
```

Comment: Thank you ! That's work ! If I would like to add a condition `$('input[data-start=0]').length > 0 || $('input[data-start=1]').length > 0 && $('div.frm_imc').length > 0)`. Is it possible ?

Comment: @Jandon Yes, that would certainly work. There are more efficient ways of doing it perhaps, but it would definitely work.